# Get the largest substrings which are the same in both strings

Tags: java

I am trying to find the largest substrings which are in both strings (minimum length of 3).  So if I have:

```
String test1 = "testthatthisworks";
String test2 = "testthisthat";
```

I need the answer to be:

```
String[] Answer = ["test", "that", "this"];
```

My one problem is this needs to be as fast as possible.  My current solution is to with a substring of length 3 from the smallest string, and then to see if this exists in the bigger string, if it does increment the size of the substring, if not move the substring along 1 point.  The problem is that this is very slow as the strings grow in length.  Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modification of the `LCS algorithm`, it will return all maximum length matches
of maximum size:

```
public static Collection<String> longestCommonSubstrings(String S1, String S2){
  return longestCommonSubstrings(S1, S2, 0);
}

public static Collection<String> longestCommonSubstrings(String S1, String S2, int minimumLength){

Collection<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int Max = minimumLength;

for (int i = 0; i < S1.length(); i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < S2.length(); j++){
    int x = 0;
    int y = Math.min(S1.length()-i,S2.length()-j);
    while (x < y && (S1.charAt(i + x) == S2.charAt(j + x) )){
      x++;
    }
    if (x > Max){
      Max = x;
      indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      indexes.add(i);
    }else if (x == Max){
      indexes.add(i);
    }
  }
}
Collection<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
for (Integer i : indexes){
  results.add(S1.substring(i, (i + Max)));
}
return results;
}
```

Comment: Hi BevynQ, unfortunately that only prints out 1 result if I feed in the strings given in the question.  Thanks though.

Comment: yes it will return testth. I assumed there was an error in the test case. can you provide a reason why test,this,that is correct and testth is not.

Answer (score 2):

Your are looking for the [Longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)

[Java Implementation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring)

Comment: Unfortunately that only gets one result, and the problem is once you get the first result how do you get the 2nd.  Also once you have the first substring, how do you stop it being included in subsequent ones.  The link is helpful though, but is the same way I am doing it basically except I iterate through to find all substrings, but the performance is too slow.

Comment: @James I don't think it is LCS at all. Note that `("testthatthisworks", "testthisthat")` returns `["test", "that", "this"]`. Look carefully at the two arguments and observe that they are in different order. If they are `("testthatthisworks", "testthatfffthis")` then LCS would be used, because `["test", "that", "this"]` are in the same order

Comment: Hi Desolator what should I rename the question to then?  Thanks for your help answering/commenting.  Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Search for **Longest Common Subsequence(LCS)** problems and algorithms. You will get a lot of hints from the implementation of an algorithm of finding LCS of two strings. Here is an example: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/96optimization/LCS.java.html

If you trace an LCS algorithm carefully, it retrieves all the common substrings till it finds the longest one. Thus you can add some code to collect these substrings by checking their length, i.e. length > 3.

Comment: No :( it is not LCS. Review the example in the question

Comment: @Desolator no, it is related with it. an LCS algorithm solves the OP's problem before returning its output. Read my post carefully.

Comment: A substring is a subsequence, but a subsequence is not always a substring.

Comment: @SoufianeHassou you are right =) thanks. i just wanted to give an idea to the OP. i missed that point =(

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez note that `("testthatthisworks", "testthisthat")` returns `["test", "that", "this"]`. Look carefully at the two arguments and observe that they are in different order.

Comment: Hi BlueBullet,  thanks for the reply, I think that the others pointed out the issue with the solution you gave.  Cheers, James